# How to make long "if" statement?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a long `if` statement where it asks you for a sign up or login, but when I get to the login part there is a syntax error. Any tips?

```py
registration = input("Do you have a registration")
if registration == "No":
    name = input("Type your name: ")
    surname = input("Type your surname: ")
    userp1 = name[0]+ surname.capitalize()
    print(userp1)
    password = input("Enter your password\n")
    userInput = input("Type your login details\n")
if userInput == userp1:
    userInput = input("Password?\n")
    if userInput== password:                 
        print("Welocome")
change = input("Do you want to change your username?")
if change == "No":
    print("You logged in as" , userp1)
else:
    userp1 = input("What would your new username be?")
    print("You logged in as",userp1)
else:
    print("Login")
```

Comment: What does SyntaxError say in its message? They are usually very descriptive.

Comment: Is the snippet you show copy-pasted as is? You haven't modified it in any way, including adding extra indentation? Because right now the indentation is not correct or consistent.

Comment: First of all, change `else` in line 16 to `elif` and provide us with traceback

Comment: I think the indentations in the questing might be wrong. If you think are not and this is the exact code you run, yes there is a syntax error. Please inform us if this is the exact code you run, including indentations and all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing two `else` statement consecutively in the last lines, and it is invalid syntax. You can put an if statement in another if statement, and you have to. This is working code but I am not sure if it is what you trying to make:

```
registration = input("Do you have a registration")
if registration == "No":
    name = input("Type your name: ")
    surname = input("Type your surname: ")
    userp1 = name[0]+ surname.capitalize()
    print(userp1)
    password = input("Enter your password\n")
    userInput = input("Type your login details\n")
    if userInput == userp1:
         userInput = input("Password?\n")
         if userInput== password:                 
           print("Welocome")
    change = input("Do you want to change your username?")
    if change == "No":
       print("You logged in as" , userp1)
    else:
       userp1 = input("What would your new username be?")
       print("You logged in as",userp1)
else:
    print("Login")
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to do.Thank you very much

Comment: @ADanailov Indentation matters! Always take care about your indentation.

Comment: If it helped you, can you mark me as answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not well indented. Be aware that python is sensetive to indentation.
You also don't specify what is the error you are getting.
So I take the liberty and tried to do a code that matches at maximum to your code.
Here it is:

```
registration = input("Do you have a registration")
if registration == "No":
   name = input("Type your name: ")
   surname = input("Type your surname: ")
   userp1 = name[0]+ surname.capitalize()
   print(userp1)
   password = input("Enter your password\n")
   userInput = input("Type your login details\n")
   if userInput == userp1:
       userInput = input("Password?\n")
       if userInput== password:                 
         print("Welocome")
   change = input("Do you want to change your username?")
   if change == "No":
      print("You logged in as" , userp1)
   else:
      userp1 = input("What would your new username be?")
      print("You logged in as",userp1)
else:
    print("Login")
```

Comment: The error was invalid syntax. Now it's all sorted,thanks

Comment: @ADanailov just one more thing. If you want to respect the standard of the python, try always to indent with 4 spaces. It is not an obligation but it is better if you do it.